# scrapy formrequest get keywords from text file

Tags: python-2.7, scrapy

I want to crawl a list of words in the search, but it only crawls the first word.
And the list of keywords is like 1 word on each line.

This is part of my code:

```
...
def parse(self, response):
...
def after_login(self, response):
...


def start_request(self, response):

    with open('keywords.txt', 'rt') as f:
        for keys in f.readlines():
                query = keys.strip()
                key = {'keywords': query}
                results = FormRequest.from_response(response,formdata=key,callback=self.parse_pa$
                yield results

def parse_page(self,response):
...
```

if i put yield results outside the for loop, gives me only the last keyword.(which makes sense to get last keyword)
i ve changed the for loop code couple of times.

Thank you in advance

***UPDATE:***

This is what i get:

```
INFO: Spider opened
[scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
[scrapy.extensions.telnet] DEBUG: Telnet console listening on 127.0.0.1:6026
[scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://www.advertcn.com/search.php?mod=forum> (referer: None)
[scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect] DEBUG: Redirecting (302) to <GET http://www.advertcn.com/search.php?mod=forum&searchid=313&orderby=lastpost&ascdesc=desc&searchsubmit=yes&kw=AdCombo> from <POST http://www.advertcn.com/search.php?mod=forum>
[scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://www.advertcn.com/search.php?mod=forum&searchid=313&orderby=lastpost&ascdesc=desc&searchsubmit=yes&kw=AdCombo> (referer: http://www.advertcn.com/search.php?mod=forum)
...
"It crawls the first word"
...
[scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
[scrapy.statscollectors] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:
{'downloader/request_bytes': 1268,
 'downloader/request_count': 3,
 'downloader/request_method_count/GET': 2,
 'downloader/request_method_count/POST': 1,
 'downloader/response_bytes': 9093,
 'downloader/response_count': 3,
 'downloader/response_status_count/200': 2,
 'downloader/response_status_count/302': 1,
 'finish_reason': 'finished',
 'finish_time': datetime.datetime(...),
 'item_scraped_count': 25,
 'log_count/DEBUG': 29,
 'log_count/INFO': 7,
 'log_count/WARNING': 1,
 'memusage/max': 50585600,
 'memusage/startup': 50585600,
 'request_depth_max': 1,
 'response_received_count': 2,
 'scheduler/dequeued': 3,
 'scheduler/dequeued/memory': 3,
 'scheduler/enqueued': 3,
 'scheduler/enqueued/memory': 3,
 'start_time': datetime.datetime(...)}
 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider closed (finished)
```

So it only crawl's the first word in the txt file...doenst crawl any others words

Comment: so, is it a problem with the `for` or with the request entering `parse_page`?

Comment: The problem is with the for...its not parsing all the keywords....everything else works fine...if i enter every word manualy in the formdata it works

Comment: The logic looks right, paste your complete log of scrapy

Comment: @Omega are you using `start_request` or `start_requests` - the later is the correct one to use...

Comment: i m using start_request. and i also used 'parse' instead of start_request....if i put start_requests it gives me error:  start_requests() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)